# Databricks SQL IsNull Statement

Tags: databricks, isnull

I'm new to Databricks and running into syntax issues with my TSQL habits. I'm using Databricks/Azure. I'm looking for the proper way to write the following Databricks SQL. Not every company has revenue for all three years and I'm looking to replace a null value with 0.

co_family table has a column with global_key (primary) with various attributes going across.
main_revenue table has a column with global_key (primary) with the last five yr revenue in a xtab format.

```
%sql

Select
   f.global_key as glb_num
  ,f.global_name as glb_name
  ,IsNull(r.tm2016, 0) as tm2016
  ,IsNull(r.tm2017, 0) as tm2017
  ,IsNull(r.tm2018, 0) as tm2018

FROM co_family as f -- Company Structure
Left Join main_revenue as r -- Revenue
  On f.global_key = r.global_key
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coalesce is supported in Databricks tsql

```
%sql

Select
   f.global_key as glb_num
  ,f.global_name as glb_name
  ,coalesce(r.tm2016, 0) as tm2016
  ,coalesce,(r.tm2017, 0) as tm2017
  ,coalesce,(r.tm2018, 0) as tm2018

FROM co_family as f -- Company Structure
Left Join main_revenue as r -- Revenue
  On f.global_key = r.global_key
```